# Error in Setting Extent using python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, extents, runtimeerror

Using ArcGIS 10.2.2
I am trying to set the extent in environment settings using arcpy.env.extent

My code is here:

```
for lyrVec in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrVec.name == "Thresholds":
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyrVec)
        lyrVecPath = desc.path + '\\' + str(lyrVec) + '.shp'
        fixedpath = os.path.normpath(lyrVecPath)
        arcpy.env.extent = lyrVecPath
```

Error message is thrown up:

> RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment

Comment: Have you tried it with another shapefile?

Comment: Have you tried printing `lyrVecPath`?  I suspect that it may not be a reachable dataset but, in any event, what you have provided here appears to be a copy/paste of some code from your script instead of a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that works up to where you are stuck.

Comment: You have specified `fixedpath = os.path.normpath(lyrVecPath)` but still use `arcpy.env.extent = lyrVecPath` instead of `arcpy.env.extent = fixedpath`.  Is there a reason you needed to fix the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set the extent using a layer in your MXD you do not need to specify the path of the underlying feature class.  `arcpy.env.extent` can be set to the actual layer.

```
>>> print arcpy.env.extent
None
>>> arcpy.env.extent = "testPoint"
>>> print arcpy.env.extent
1880391.189 5821879.3835 1885687.1515 5825657.3949 NaN NaN NaN NaN
>>>
```

Try changing your code to find your layer and then set extent using that layer name.

```
for lyrVec in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrVec.name == "Thresholds":
        arcpy.env.extent = lyrVec.name
```

If there is a reason you do need to specify your underlying shapefile, try the following

```
for lyrVec in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrVec.name == "Thresholds":
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyrVec)
        lyrVecPath = os.path.join(desc.path, "{0}.shp".format(lyrVec))
        arcpy.env.extent = lyrVecPath
```